# How to specify localized forms of CJK scripts in Python's PIL ImageFont?

Tags: python, fonts, python-imaging-library, cjk, truetype

CJK scripts ([CJK Unified Ideographs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CJK_Unified_Ideographs)) share the same Unicode code points, the distinction between simplified Chinese, traditional Chinese and Kanji can only be handled by the font.

Some fonts support several localized forms (simplified Chinese, traditional Chinese, Kanji, etc.) at the same time. For example, [Arial Unicode.ttf](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/typography/font-list/arial-unicode-ms) has 4 [locl](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/typography/opentype/otspec140/features_ko#locl) in the [GSUB table](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/typography/opentype/spec/gsub): `jpn`, `kor`, `zhs`, `zht`, which handles different localized forms for CJK scripts. `jpn` is the default one, which corresponds to Kanji.

How can I choose the localized forms to use in Python? More specifically, I would like to control the localized forms when working with `PIL` [package](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/ImageFont.html).

```py
image_font = ImageFont.truetype(font="Arial Unicode.ttf", size=10) # PIL.ImageFont.FreeTypeFont object
```

Is this localized form specification even possible with `PIL` version `8.0.1`?

Comment: rather then "locl", those are script "langsys" (language system) entries. As for how to indicate script: that sounds like something you should ask them on their own [issue tracker](https://github.com/python-pillow/Pillow/issues), because having that added to the documentation, or added to the _code_ as well as the documentation, would help a lot of folks, not just you. Did you file an issue?

Comment: Hi, @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans, thanks for your reply. If I understand correctly, you mean that the distinction between simplified Chinese, traditional Chinese and Kanji is handled by `langsys` instead of `locl`, is my understanding correct? I did not succeed in finding comprehensible information on this subject. I will file an issue on their issue tracker.

Comment: OpenType GSUB/GPOS (which this relates to) is fairly complex, and relies on the font knowing which script and language are active, and which features should be enabled or not. (script and language are _required_ to do correct shaping, features are mostly for ornamentation, such as old-vs new style 字, vertical kerning, etc). I don't see anything that lets you specify that, so that's definitely something to ask for on the issue tracker, because Chinese, Japanese, and legacy Korean/Vietnamese use wildly different variants for quite a lot of characters.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans, thank you for the explanation. I filed an issue on their issue tracker.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found the solution. To specify the forms of CJK characters in Python's `PIL`, it is sufficient to specify the `language` parameter in the `ImageDraw.text()` ([link](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/ImageDraw.html#PIL.ImageDraw.ImageDraw.text)), which requires `libraqm` package.

The following example shows the result:

```py
languages = ["", "zh", "zh-Hans", "zh-CN", "zh-TW", "zh-HK"]
char_ = "骨"
font = ImageFont.truetype("Arial Unicode.ttf", size=32)
fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=2, ncols=3, figsize=(20, 8))
axes = axes.ravel() 
for i, c in enumerate([char_] * len(languages)):
    img = Image.new("L", (64, 64), 255)
    draw = ImageDraw.Draw(img)
    if i == 0:
        draw.text((0, 0), c, font=font)
    else:
        draw.text((0, 0), c, font=font, language=languages[i])
    axes[i].imshow(img) 
    axes[i].set_title(languages[i] + " {}".format(ord(char_)))
plt.show()
```

[image]